# Unable to remove the component from the list (React Hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm trying to remove the React state (ListItem component) when I click on a button to trigger removal. However, React fails to rerender after I remove it from the state. How do I properly do this?

```
import {Button, List} from "@material-ui/core";
import React, {useLayoutEffect, useState} from "react";
import useRules from "../sharedStates/Rules";
import useLanguange from "../sharedStates/Languages";
import axios from "axios";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";


const REFRESH_JWT_URL = "/auth/api/refresh_jwt/"
const BLOCKCHAIN_DELETE_URL = "blockchain/api/rule/?id="
const DATALAKE_REMOVE_URL = "datalake/api/remove_rule"

//TODO: Implement Translation.
//TODO: Implement Delete Rule.
const RuleList = ({
  rules,
  rerender,
  userID,
  groupIDs,
  orgID,
  jwtRefresh,
  jwtAccess,
  username
                  }) => {
  const [_rules, _setRules] = useState(rules)


  const editRule = () => {
    console.log("Todo: Implement Edit Rule")
  }

  const removeRule = (ruleId) => {
    console.log("TODO: IMPLEMENT DELETE RULE IN THE DB")

    //TODO: Figure out the reason this is not working
    // _setRules(_rules.filter(rule => rule.id !== ruleId));
  }



  return (
    <List>
        {
          _rules.map((rule => (
            <ListItem key={rule.id}>
              <p> {lang.label.I} {" "} <b>{lang.label[rule.action]}</b> {lang.label.toAccessTags} </p>
              <p> <b>
                {
                  Object.values(rule.access).map(tag =>
                    tag.name
                  ).join(", ")
                }
              </b>
              </p>
              <p>{lang.label.toTheProfesional} {" "} <b>{rule.granteeID}</b></p>
              <p>{lang.label.ruleExpiresIn} {rule.expires}</p>
              <Button onClick={editRule}>{lang.label.Edit}</Button>
              <Button onClick={removeRule(rule.id)}>{lang.label.Remove}</Button>
            </ListItem>
          )))
        }
    </List>



  )
}

export default RuleList
```

and This will be shown in the page:
[image]

When I uncomment this line,     `// _setRules(_rules.filter(rule => rule.id !== ruleId));`. The list is not shown to the page even before I click the remove button.

Please advise.

Thanks before.

Comment: `onClick={removeRule(rule.id)}` pass removeRule in arrow function like this`'onClick={()=>{removeRule(rule.id)}}` because when your rules are rendered removeRule() is called immediately so you must call it like this

Answer (score 4):

You have to use arrow function like this `onClick={() => removeRule(rule.id)}` instead of `onClick={removeRule(rule.id)}`.